# Javascript - Generate date from daynumber

Tags: javascript

Say I have the day number of the year.

How can I generate the date from that?

EX. Today's day number is `265`

How can I get the output `9/23/2015`?

Yesterday's day number was `264`, how can I get the output of `9/22/2015`?

Comment: for `264` it'll be `09/22/2015`

Answer (score 1):

Try like this

```
var year = 2015;
var date = new Date(year,0,1); // get the first date of year
var numberOfDaysToAdd=264;
date.setDate(date.getDate() + numberOfDaysToAdd); // add days to that date
console.log(date);
```

Answer (score 0):

You may simply use `Date()`:

```js
var days = 265;
var now = new Date();
now.setMonth(0); // jan
now.setDate(days);
var date = 1 + now.getMonth();
var pad = function(v) {
  return 10 > v ? '0' + v : v;
};
date = pad(date) + '/' + pad(now.getDate()) + '/' + now.getFullYear();
document.write(date);
```